# What are the solutions Firebase offers to reduce cost for Realtime Database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase realtime database.
The project works like a chat application.
We are constantly downloading / uploading.
But the cost seems too high. All data is downloaded again every get 1 message. What can I do to reduce the cost of this?

Instead of downloading data again every time I think of creating a cache. What should we pay attention to when creating the cache?
What are the solutions Firebase offers to reduce cost for realtime database?

Thanks, best regards

Comment: More than likely you have created code that is uploading and downloading too frequently, or it could be due to your structure. This is concerning **All data is downloaded again every get 1 message** as you should not be downloading all of your data for every message. Perhaps you can share your code so we can take a look. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

The [pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) of Firebase is pretty clear. The cost for the Realtime Database is based on:

- The amount of data you store in the database.
- The amount of data that is read from the database.

So those are the two factors you'll need to pay attention to if you want to reduce the cost.

Which one has the highest impact really depends on where your cost is coming from, which you didn't say. But the most common one is to look if you can reduce the number of times each client downloads the same data by local caching. If you're using the native mobile SDKs for iOS and Android (which you also don't mention), you can often already accomplish some reduction by [enabling disk caching](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities#section-disk-persistence).

Comment: Hello Frank thanks for your answer. I have 2.9 MB storage data in firebase realtime database, but although I am the only person using the application, I use 1 - 1.5gb download quota per day.
My highest impact is downloading 
I'm coding for Android.
All data is automatically downloaded again when a new data is added.
What is my problem? Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should not be downloading all of your data for every post. Please update the question so we can take a look.